# Animation not working when I hover over image

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to add a sweep to the right animation on my image so that when you hover the image it sweeps to the right and it shows the text on hover as well. I got this to work just find with buttons but I am lost on how to go about doing this. This is what I have so far with my code:

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.portfolio-box img {
  width: 300px; /*changed this from 100% for the q*/
  height:auto;
  /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

.portfolio-mask {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #060606;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}

.portfolio-mask:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.portfolio-mask:hover {
  opacity: .85;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-box">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt="Coffee">
  <div class="portfolio-mask">
    <p class="portfolio-text">Design Mock up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your CSS to make it work smooth and without insane jumping when you hover left side of the image. Here is the CSS and below is the description what changes and why I have made.

```
.portfolio-box {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}

.portfolio-box img {
    width: 300px; /*changed this from 100% for the q*/
    height:auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    display: block;
    /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

.portfolio-mask {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #060606;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-mask {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    opacity: .85;
    color: white;
}
```

Changes I made:

1. Added `display: inline-block;` for `.portfolio-box` -  to make it be as big as image inside.
2. Added `display: block;` for image to prevent 2-3px empty space under image when it is displayed inline (default).
3. Added `transition: all 0.5s ease-out;` for image, to prevent jumping when change position.
4. I changed transition from `transform` to `all` to animate not only move but opacity of mask container.
5. Animation are now added for hover on `.portfolio-box`, because it is static container, which is very important for effect you want to achieve - if you add animation on image hover then you will get infinite animation, because when you hover your mouse above image then it will slide to the right and after then it will be no longer hovered so it will go back to initial state and then it will be hovered again so it will go to the right... repeat initity ;)

Comment: A few questions I have. When I hover over the image I still want to see the opacity change so you can still see the picture and the code you provided doesn't make that work. Why wouldn't it work for adding the animations to the .portfolio-mask class?

Comment: Opacity change of image or mask? You want to slide image to the right and still see it? I don't understand. You have animations on `portfolio-mask` class, but hover is fired on its container, because at the beginning mask is outside of the container, so you cannot hover it by mouse.

Comment: Let me link something to show you what I mean and what I am going for. Your code is really close to what I need, but maybe this link will show you what I am going for. Scroll down to the portfolio section and hover over the images and you will see what I mean. The only difference is I want my animation to sweep to the right. Here is the link: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/royme-portfolio-template/full_screen_preview/20591752?_ga=2.79292752.576178220.1550639643-1381743554.1550639643

Comment: Ok, so I just removed animation for image, it will stay under mask now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Really appreciate it like I said I had no problems doing this when it comes to buttons because I would target one class. One last question if you don't mind. Is the way I structured my HTML for this a good way to go about it or is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description that what you are trying to do is a `transform`. For this, just add a `translateX` transform (of your desired size) to the css.

Hope this helps.

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.portfolio-box img {
  width: 300px; /*changed this from 100% for the q*/
  height:auto;
  /*object-fit: contain;*/
}
.portfolio-box img.animate:hover{
  transform: translateX(5em);
}
.portfolio-mask {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #060606;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}

.portfolio-mask:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.portfolio-mask:hover {
  opacity: .85;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-box">
  <img class="animate"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG" alt="Coffee">
  <div class="portfolio-mask">
    <p class="portfolio-text">Design Mock up</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't support SCSS in snippets, you'd have more luck testing the 'sweep right'/transform with the text in your own code or on codepen..

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something like this but in my case I'm using an image:

https://codepen.io/Jtwa/pen/vNmaYw

Comment: @DanielD the css given in that codepen will work for an image too. I didn't understand that that was what you were after.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but I want that same effect whenever I hover of the image, and not the image itself to move.

Comment: @DanielD https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xexWeL same as your codepen, but with an image in the div

Comment: @DanielD you can change the colour of the sweep by changing  the background in the css.  (and feel free to accept my answer :) )

Comment: The codepen keeps on refreshing and won't stay still.

Comment: @DanielD I put it in a jsfiddle.  Here it is https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/1eon6km0/

Comment: That works and all but you forgot to factor in my code that I posted here. I want my text to appear when you hover over the image as well.

Comment: @DanielD well it's a start and as it's 1:48 am here, I'm off for the night. Good luck.